# Unused git project wants to use it again

Tags: git, github

I had cloned a project two  times in my workspace due to some reason that I don't know now. I was working on one of them. Since later I wanted to delete one of them because of duplicated projects. but by mistake I deleted the project in which I was working on since I pulled the latest data for the other one. On pull latest, I had observed git status like this:

```
$ git status 
# On branch feature/2.8.0
# All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
#   (use "git commit" to conclude merge)
#
# Changes to be committed:
#
#   modified:   ../ChicagoBoss/rebar.config
#   modified:   ../deps.zip
#   modified:   boss.config
#   modified:   boss.production.config
#   modified:   boss.qa.config
#   modified:   boss.staging.config
#   modified:   priv/static/js/ancestorEdit.js
#   modified:   priv/static/js/heirEdit.js
#   modified:   priv/static/js/ihtx.eval.utils.js
#   modified:   priv/static/js/ihtx.property.list.js
#   modified:   priv/static/js/ihtx.property.show.js
#   modified:   priv/static/js/prvl_unlisted_securities_0102_h250527.js
#   new file:   priv/static/js/prvl_unlisted_securities_0500_h250527.js
#   modified:   src/controller/inheritance_tax_eval_controller.erl
#   modified:   src/lib/data_util.erl
[...]
```

I have merged the unmerged paths. Now here it is showing that `# Changes to be committed:`. But I don't want to commit anything from there. I'm confused what should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in the middle of a merge. It says you fixed conflicts. Did you?

If you want to stop the merge (and undo the conflict resolutions):

```
$ git merge --abort
```

For safety, you may want to commit these changes, just so you have them:

```
$ git commit
```

You can always reset back from there to 'undo' that commit if you want:

```
$ git stash
$ git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
$ git stash pop
```

The `stash` and `stash pop` will protect any other changes that aren't staged currently from disappearing, also just in case. At least this way you'll have committed these changes. If you realize later that you want them, you can look in the reflog (`git reflog`) and find the commit and reset back to it again.